# Identifying fonts/typefaces

Tags: fonts, typography

I'm trying to identify two similar (to my eye at least) but different serif fonts to use for a custom LaTeX template.

- The first is that used in *Superstring Theory* by Green, Schwarz and Witten. It looks a little Garamond-ish -- the book is published by Cambridge University Press if that helps, but is more than 30 years old at this point.

[image: GSW]

- The second is in *Complex Geometry: An Introdyction* by Daniel Huybrechts. Huybrechts is published by Springer and uses "a Springer LaTeX macro package", presumably the typeface is available somewhere in TeXlive?

[image: Huybrechts]

They both sort of seem similar to the Latin Modern family, but ... rounder? Would appreciate any suggestions for anything similar!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: We have the canonical https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture, does that answer your question?

Comment: @Marijn @doncherry Thanks - this is helpful, in particular `pdffonts` and using `evince` and looking at the properties. For the second book I get `Embedded-H` but in both cases they seem to be Times Roman/Nimbus Roman/Century variants. The fonts on the LaTeX Font Catalogue don't quite seem to match though.